# How to horizontal scroll other items in list view by scrolling one item?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have many items in the listView, each item in the listView has an HorizontalScrollView. When I scroll one item, all the other items in the listView should scroll itself. How can I implement this?
The code for my listview is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/admin_ip_listView"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_ip_picture"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView_ip_ref_number"
        />
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="900dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView_ip_q1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView_ip_q2"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView_ip_q3"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView_ip_q4"/>

      </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/texview_ip_avg"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

But why you fix android:layout_width with 900dp in HorizontalScrollView and LinearLayout?

Can you try to change: layout_width

like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">


<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```